# Converting text range to single integer

Tags: r, data-cleaning

if I had a set of data containing the following:

```
0-3
0-3
0-3
2-6
2-6
2-6
2-6
2-6
1-3
```

How would I covert this into a single number, say the upper value, or even better the average of the two numbers either side of the hyphen?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read.table` to split on `-` and use `rowMeans` to get the mean.

```
x <- c("0-3", "2-6", "1-3")

rowMeans(read.table(text=x, sep="-"))
#[1] 1.5 4.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use tidyverse for this

```
d <- c("0-1", "1-1","2-0")

data.frame(d) %>% separate(col = d, sep = "-", into = c("l", "r")) %>% 
  mutate(average = (as.numeric(l) + as.numeric(r) / 2))

  l r averaged
1 0 1      0.5
2 1 1      1.5
3 2 0      2.0
```

Comment: set `convert = T` in `separate` so that you don't need to use `as.numeric` in `mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution

```
sapply(strsplit(dat,"-"),function(v) mean(as.numeric(v)))
```

or

```
rowMeans(`class<-`(do.call(rbind,strsplit(dat,"-")),"numeric"))
```

such that

```
# [1] 1.5 4.0 2.0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- c("0-3", "2-6", "1-3")
```